# Using python to extract out data from excel csv file

Tags: python, scripting

I have encountered a problem on extracting the data from a database1.csv file. My database1.csv file contain a million of data and I need to extract out certain column of data which I need for it. The following figure is my coding and I found an error when running the coding. The error I got is Error: unknown dialect.

For your information: 
1) I need to extract out the entire certain column which contain the information "GWM" from database1.csv file. 
2) After I extracted the data and I need to put all of them into a new excel file which is result.csv file. 
3) The word "GWM" is the word that I selected to extract out the certain entire column

Any recommended suggestion can be used to improve and edit my coding? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
input_file = pd.read_csv("database1.csv")
output_file = open('result2.csv','w')
for column in input_file:
    count = 0
    for word in column:
        if word == "GWM":
            count = count + 1
print (column)
output_file.write(column)
```

Comment: using `pandas.read_csv` you can read full file or only selected columns.

Comment: if you use `csv.reader` then you should use `csv.writer`. Using `open()` and `write()` you can create inproper CSV file because it will add `[ ]` to every row when `write()` converts list to string.

Comment: always put code as text, not image. My python can't run code from image. And we can't use it to create new code with modifications.

Comment: Hi @LAI, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important to read [the formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before asking your question. Posting your source code as an image is not acceptable. Good luck with your question!

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post. Sorry for any inconveniences caused.

Answer (score 2):

A good recommendation I can make for reading/manipulating csv data is pandas. For example reading data using pandas is as simple as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv( "my/path/to/database1.csv" )
```

The result is a dataframe. A tabular representation of your data which can be manipulated in any number of ways. Writing to a csv is also another one liner. You can use the following:

```
df.to_csv( "my/path/to/output.csv" )
```

There are other methods available for working with excel data, such as pd.read_excel and df.to_excel. More available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html). Hope this helps.